# Regex to Match "***anything***Customer No. 9999999 ***anything***"

Tags: regex, vb.net

I wanna use `Regex.Ismatch` function in VB.net to match Pattern `***anything***Customer No. 9999999 ***anything***`

i.e "Customer No. " -> Static
After "Customer No. " 7 numeric character -> Dynamic

I Regex tried so far `^ .*Customer No\. [0-9]+ .*$`. I am close but it doesn't accept if there is only `Customer No. 9999999` it match only if there is prefix and suffix

Comment: Escape `.` by preceding `\\``. Even in the comments I've to escape `\\` by preceding `\\`

Comment: didn't understood can you please re-write

Comment: Works For Me. Check [here](https://regex101.com/r/yC5iO5/1)

Comment: if it's always 7 digits, don't use `+`, instead use `{7}`. if it's 1 to 7 digits use `{1,7}`.

Comment: bro what if i want to match `“Customer No. 9999999 ”` Please note there is space at the end and its static always

Comment: @Tushar Escaping is not necessary to get a match, because the expression becomes more restrictive. Without escaping the expression matches any character after `No` - for example, it would match `Customer Non 9999999` as well.

Comment: @user3800108 For spaces at the end, https://regex101.com/r/yC5iO5/2

Comment: Maybe even better use `Customer No\. (?:0|[1-9][0-9]{0,6}) ` to avoid leading zeros.

Comment: Sorry there is one edit i want this rule to be used as string contains instead of string match :( now it clicked something like `*^Customer No\. [0-9]+\s$*`

Comment: `^ *Customer No\. [0-9]+\s*$` worked

Comment: `^ *Customer No\. [0-9]+ *$` note the spaces `\s` will also match tabs. And this does have no restriction on the number, e.g. 100 zeros is a valid number.

Comment: no its not matching `dsxzx  Customer No. 9999999 xccx`

Comment: You should edit your question and clearly state what you have and what's your goal, otherwise it would just be guessing, anyway you are almost there, I don't see why you would want to do it like that, but you could do: `^.*?Cus`...`.*$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this pattern a try:

```
"Customer No\. \d{7}"
```

This is capturing the literal "Customer No. " plus 7 consecutive digits into which you can access like:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim data As String = "***anything***Customer No. 9999999 ***anything***"
        Dim matcher As Match = Regex.Match(data, "Customer No\. \d{7}")
        If matcher.Success Then
            Console.WriteLine(matcher.Value)
        End If
    End Sub
End Module
```

Results:

```
Customer No. 9999999
```

Comment: Ok, this is what you wanted, btw. both `.*?` are superfluous and therefore also the brackets, it's just group 0.

Comment: IT MATCHES EVEN IF "Customer NO." I want case sensitive one

Comment: @user3800108 You're saying that for a string "***anything***Customer NO. 9999999 ***anything***", the regex still matches?  I'm not seeing that result.

Comment: @user3800108 Also, note the changes I've made to the answer.  Even these changes to not match for "***anything***Customer NO. 9999999 ***anything***".  The match will be false.

Answer (score 1):

c#:

```
 string s = " Customer No. 9999999";
                Regex regex = new Regex(@"^Customer No. +[0-9]{7}$");
                Match match = regex.Match(s);
                if (match.Success)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("not match");
                }
```

vb:

```
Dim s As String = "Customer No. 9999999"
Dim regex As New Regex(@"^Customer No. +[0-9]{7}$")
Dim match As Match = regex.Match(s)
If match.Success Then
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value)
Else
    Console.WriteLine("not match")
End If
```

Comment: Hi what if i need to match `dsxzx Customer No. 9999999 xccx`

Comment: @user3800108 you mean dsxzx  is a 5 letter word?

Comment: no i am close with this `^ .*Customer No\. [0-9]+ .*$`

but it is not accepting `Customer No. 9999999`

i want to match this

`***anything**Customer No. 9999999 ***anything***`

Comment: @user3800108 I am not sure about required  Regex, why dont you compare that with vb.net

Comment: @user3800108 I think, you  better to choose vb.net for this comparision